# Firefox (v82, v83) (32 bit) Debugger - Inline Variable Preview not enabling - how to fix it?

Tags: debugging, firefox

(Running on Windows 7).

On some earlier version of Firefox (in the Debugger Source Pane) when paused, I used to be able to move the mouse pointer across source code and if I hovered above a variable then a little pop-up window (like tool tips) would appear just above the variable, indicating the current value.  (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/UI_Tour) for a brief, illustrtated, overview of the Firefox Debugger user interface).

But this preview feature stopped working several months ago following an upgrade and I didnt have time to look into it then.

Recently on Firefox version 82 and now on version 83 (the latest) the problem persists.

I can toggle the menu item "Inline Variable Preview" in the Debugger Settings Menu - but it has no discernible effect.

When I use the debugger in the Opera browser (but the same laptop)  then the Inline Variable Preview works just fine.

Does anyone know how what might be the problem in Firefox, and how to fix it?